# Debian Stretch: Samba Winbind Offline Logon Not working - kerberos keytab not persistent after reboot?

Tags: samba, active-directory, kerberos, domain, winbind

This is being tried on`Debian stretch` referred to as 9.6 in `/etc/debian_version`

I'm in a Windows Domain environment with two 2012R2 controllers that have IDMU/Unix Attributes.

Other versions of stuff:

```
Samba version 4.5.12-Debian
winbindd version 4.5.12-Debian
```

Also installed:

```
krb5-user
libnss-winbind
libpam-winbind
oddjob-mkhomedir
```

I'm hoping I can log in with domain users at default console user credential prompt.  I've been trying ALL SORTS of stuff, but can't seem to get it to work.

I think my issue is that kerberos keytabs aren't persistent after reboot?

I followed this guide on the official Wiki: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/PAM_Offline_Authentication

I tried it with the default setting of `/tmp/krb5cc` but no luck - thought process is that this location is not persistent after reboot?

So then I thought maybe I could get the keytab to save in another location besides /tmp so I set KRB5CACHE environment variable to a folder that's persistent - and I can get `kinit` to save there

But I can't get the `/etc/security/pam_winbind.conf` user keytab info to save in a different folder

Even if I change `krb5_ccache_type = FILE:/my/persistent/location/krb5cc` but it still always saves it as `/tmp/krb5cc` when I invoke:

```
# wbinfo -K DOMAIN\\username%password
```

I CAN get the response of:

```
plaintext kerberos password authentication for [WEBTOOL\avery%Person01] succeeded (requesting cctype: FILE)
user_flgs: NETLOGON_CACHED_ACCOUNT
credentials were put in: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
```

but when I reboot it doesn't matter --

and ONLY if I invoke `smbcontrol winbind offline` - `/etc/samba/smb.conf` param `winbind offline logon = yes` does not seem to work, even though it's set.

(and yes, I have reset samba and winbind using `/etc/init.d` and `systemctl` after editing `.conf` files, not to mention rebooting over and over again to try the offline winbind login)

I even tried giving my domain user a UNIX passwd.  Not even that worked.

So what's up ? Anybody have login for domain users after reboot?

Comment: Are you particularly wedded to `winbind` or would you consider `sssd`?

Comment: I prefer winbind, it seems to work better with IDMU/Unix Attributes

Comment: Grr.  I just set up an Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS VM and got the offline winbind login to work just fine.  What gives, Debian?  I thought you were cool...